# Format expiry date on a credit card in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How can I format a text input to `MM/YY` in React Native?

I have made an onChange function

```
handleExpiry(expiry) {
  if (expiry.length >= 2) {
    expiry = expiry.substr(0, 2) + '/' + (expiry.substr(3) || '')
  }

  this.setState({
    expiry
  })
}
```

but it lets me write `DD/` because `expiry.substr(3)` is always null.

- I want to strip non-numeric characters. I guess it's done with
  `expiry.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')`.
- I want to make sure the string is only 5 characters, which is `expiry.length <= 5`
- I want to make sure that the first two characters are less than or
  equal 12, so it might be with `parseInt(expiry.substr(0, 2), 10) > 0
  && parseInt(expiry.substr(0, 2), 10) <= 12`.
- I want to make sure that the third character is '/', which might be with `expiry.charAt(2) === '/'`
- And finally, I want to make sure that the remaining 2 characters are greater than 17, so it is `parseInt(expiry.substr(3), 10) >= 17`.

But I don't know how to bind it together.

Comment: can you give an example of the string that you receive as input to the function?

Comment: From start, the string is empty. Then I input "1", then "2", and then it should automatically add "/", so the string is "12/". Next, I input "1", then "9", and not the string is "12/19". I am setting maxLength on the TextInput, so it never exceeds 5 characters. However, I don't know how to validate every single input, so it always has the format "DD/MM".

Comment: Take a look at the package [react-native-masked-text](https://github.com/benhurott/react-native-masked-text). You should be able to achieve what you are trying to do with the `custom` type.